# Instance of an object in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am encountering a bug in a game I am trying to make. I am getting the following error.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This same code works fine in one of my other scripts but in this one it continues to through this error. I thought I set it to an instance of the object but I guess not.

```
UnityEngine.Component book001GUIOld = GameObject.FindWithTag("Book001Canvas").GetComponent("Canvas");
UnityEngine.Behaviour book001GUI = (UnityEngine.Behaviour)book001GUIOld;
```

Any Suggestions? Let me know if you need more of the code. I have also tried.

```
UnityEngine.Behaviour book001GUI = GameObject.FindWithTag("Book001Canvas").GetComponent("Canvas") as behaviour;
```

Comment: just find out the bottom most stack which the object is null but it shouldnt be...NullReference is one of the easiest bug to debug..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GameObject.FindWithTag](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) documentation:

> **Description**
>
> Returns one active GameObject tagged `tag`. Returns `null` if no
>   GameObject was found.

So you might want to try to catch the error:

```
var book001Canvas = GameObject.FindWithTag("Book001Canvas");

if (book001Canvass != null)
{
    UnityEngine.Component book001GUIOld = book001Canvas.GetComponent("Canvas");
}
else
{
    // Recover from not finding an object with the Book001Canvas tag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be because `GameObject.FindWithTag("Book001Canvas")` returned null,
then `.GetComponent("Canvas");` throws a exception.

Comment: GameObject seems to be a static class and .FindWithTag a static method. no?

Comment: Ah, I think you're right.